# Installation error while installing test corda node

Tags: azure, ubuntu, blockchain, corda

i am trying to create a corda test node using the following link:
[Corda Azure VM](https://docs.corda.net/azure-vm-explore.html)

I have followed the instruction as is and when i execute the command from "https://marketplace.r3.com/network" with their onetime script in the terminal `sudo ONE_TIME_DOWNLOAD_KEY=91c51b4e-d619-4a20-90c1-24120687a74d bash -c "$(curl -L https://onboarder.prod.ws.r3.com/api/user/node/TESTNET/install.sh)"`

I get the following error

[image: terminal error]

any idea on how to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you're talking about the last line (`No such file or directory`) since I don't see any errors really.
So the `corda.service` file allows you to start your Corda node when your VM starts, if it's missing; then you have to start the node manually.

I recommend that you follow the instructions in this link to create the file yourself (**start at step number 8**): https://docs.corda.net/deploying-a-node.html#linux-installing-and-running-corda-as-a-system-service

Please note that there are 2 approaches to create a service (**SystemD** and **Upstart**); so make sure that you follow the steps for only one approach (I used **SystemD**).